# Sort Array of Key-Value Paired Objects using an Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, key-value

I am trying to sort an array of key-value paired objects using the index of a second array of arrays.

Consider the following code:

```js
const sheet = [['ES'], ['MES'], ['NQ'], ['MNQ']] // sort in this order
const quotes = [{root: 'MNQ'}, {root: 'MES'}, {root: 'ES'}, {root: 'NQ'}] // sort these objects

const sorted = quotes.sort((a, b) => {
  return sheet.indexOf(a.root) - sheet.indexOf(b.root)
})

console.log(sorted)
```

When you run the above code, `sorted` has retained the same order as the original `quotes` variable and it appears as if no sort has taken place!

I feel like I'm almost there and my code just needs a small tweak to make it work.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, can you please explain the reason for the edit, so I don't make the same mistake again?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950 - it's not a big problem, but Stack Overflow is meant to be a reference site, not a discussion forum, so "thanks" etc is just noise (and we're supposed to remove them from posts when we see them)

Comment: Noted and will be less 'chatty' from now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sheet` is an array of arrays, so `sheet.indexOf` *anything* other than an array taken from `sheet` will return `-1`.

Transform `sheet` to an array of strings first:

```js
const sheet = [['ES'], ['MES'], ['NQ'], ['MNQ']]
  .map(([str]) => str);
const quotes = [{root: 'MNQ'}, {root: 'MES'}, {root: 'ES'}, {root: 'NQ'}] // sort these objects

const sorted = quotes.sort((a, b) => {
  return sheet.indexOf(a.root) - sheet.indexOf(b.root)
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Or use `.findIndex` instead of `indexOf`:

```js
const sheet = [['ES'], ['MES'], ['NQ'], ['MNQ']];
const quotes = [{root: 'MNQ'}, {root: 'MES'}, {root: 'ES'}, {root: 'NQ'}] // sort these objects

const sorted = quotes.sort((a, b) => {
  return sheet.findIndex(arr => arr[0] === a.root) - sheet.findIndex(arr => arr[0] === b.root)
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Or, for better computational complexity (`O(n log n)`), transform `sheet` into an object indexed by string, whose values are the indicies:

```js
const sheet = [['ES'], ['MES'], ['NQ'], ['MNQ']];
const sheetObj = {};
for (const [i, [str]] of sheet.entries()) {
  sheetObj[str] = i;
}
const quotes = [{root: 'MNQ'}, {root: 'MES'}, {root: 'ES'}, {root: 'NQ'}] // sort these objects

const sorted = quotes.sort((a, b) => sheetObj[a.root] - sheetObj[b.root]);

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much @CertainPerformance. I will accept your answer as soon as the 15 minute timer is over

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `indexOf` since `sheet` is an array of arrays. Try using `findIndex()` and comparing the only array element:

```js
const sheet = [['ES'], ['MES'], ['NQ'], ['MNQ']] // sort in this order
const quotes = [{root: 'MNQ'}, {root: 'MES'}, {root: 'ES'}, {root: 'NQ'}] // sort these objects

let sorted = quotes.sort((a, b) => {
  return sheet.findIndex(([x]) => x === a.root) - sheet.findIndex(([x]) => x === b.root);
})

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach (which should be more efficient than using `.sort()` for larger arrays) you could use if your `quotes` array has unique `{root}` objects would be to make a [`new Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from your `quotes` array and then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `sheet` array the `{root}` objects like so:

```js
const sheet = [['ES'], ['MES'], ['NQ'], ['MNQ']];
const quotes = [{root: 'MNQ'}, {root: 'MES'}, {root: 'ES'}, {root: 'NQ'}] // sort these objects

const lut = new Map(quotes.map(({root}) => [root, {root}]));
const sorted = sheet.map(([s]) => lut.get(s));
console.log(sorted)
```

If you're you can have duplicates, you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of a `new Map`, and then [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const sheet = [['ES'], ['MES'], ['NQ'], ['MNQ']];
const quotes = [{root: 'MNQ'}, {root: 'MES'}, {root: 'ES'}, {root: 'NQ'}, {root: 'MES'}] // sort these objects

const lut = quotes.reduce((acc, {root}) => {
  acc[root] = [...(acc[root] || []), {root}];
  return acc;
}, {});

const sorted = sheet.flatMap(([s]) => lut[s]);
console.log(sorted)
```